# pandas – Use of series question (should be easy)

Tags: python, pandas, series

Hello good people of stackoverflow. I am currently trying to answer the following question, I have the correct answer (Nolan and 7) but my answer is not in a series format and I don't know how to go about getting it to it, can anyone help?

I've included the first few questions as context to the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('imdb.xlsx')
df = xls.parse('imdb')
df_directors = xls.parse('directors')
df_countries = xls.parse('countries')

print("Data Loading Finished.")

""" Q1: 
Join three Dataframes: df, df_directors, and df_countries with an inner join.
Store the joined DataFrames in df.

Here are the steps:
1. Merge df with df_countries and assign it df
2. Merge df with df_directors and assign it to df again
There might be errors if the merge is not in this order, so please be careful.

"""

# your code here
df.head()
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_countries, how='inner', left_on='country_id', right_on='id')
df.head()
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_directors, how='inner', left_on='director_id', right_on='id')


# After the join, the resulting Dataframe should have 12 columns.
df.shape

""" Q4:
Who is the director with the most movies? First get the number of movies per "director_name", then save the director's name
and count as a series of length 1 called "director_with_most"
"""

# your code here

directors = df['director_name'].value_counts()
print(directors)

director_with_most = directors[]
directors.index[0]
directors[0]

print(director_with_most)
```

directors.index gives the result of Nolan, with directors[0] giving the number of times he appears in the database: 7.
The error I get when I check my answer (this is from a coursera course) is:

```
AssertionError: Series Expected type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, found <class 'list'> instead
```

Please help, I have been stuck on this for ages.

Cheers,

Adam

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad form to post such questions to SO, and also, there is no reason why directors[0] should have the highest count, so you are still far from solution.

However, I really hate how the assignment is formulated. What on earth does it mean for series of length 1 to contain two values? Stupid. Do this:

`director_with_most = df.director_name.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x == x.max()]`

(this will return multiple rows if max is not unique)

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

`director_with_most = df['director_name'].value_counts().head(1)`